# Replace the word suggestions in the 'Replace' pop-up in UITextView

Tags: swift, uitextview

Is there a way to feed in words, programmatically, to the 'Replace' option which pops-up when you select any text in UITextView? Like while typing, the Quick Type words suggestions can be replaced by setting the keyboard's accessory view.